# C# access arrays in a method created in a previous method

Tags: c#, arrays

Declared a public static array and created an instance of this array variable inside a button click. I have a for loop which goes through an XMLNodeList variable and stores XML for each applicant tag in the array. The first time it runs, it picks out certain fields from the XMLNodeList and displays on the front end OK - when I debug the second time it runs the method, it try's to access the array string and when i debug all the values in the array are null. There are examples I have followed using stackoverflow but havent found something useful to help me resolve the above issue.

XML example:

```
<applicant app-type=\"applicant\" designation=\"all\" sequence=\"1\" >
        <name>Test</name>
        <address>
            <address-1>123</address-1>
            <address-2>Quality St</address-2>
            <country>JP</country>
        </address>
    </addressbook>
    <nationality>
        <country />
    </nationality>
    <residence>
        <country />
    </residence>
</applicant>
<applicant app-type=\"applicant\" designation=\"all\" sequence=\"2\" >
    <name>Test</name>
    <address>
        <address-1>456</address-1>
        <address-2>Butter Road</address-2>
        <country>AM</country>
    </address>
    </addressbook>
    <nationality>
        <country />
    </nationality>
    <residence>
        <country />
    </residence>
</applicant>


public static string[] eachXML;
private static int sequenceCounter;
public static int totalNumberSequences;

  protected void QueryEPO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

XMLDocument xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc2.LoadXml(applicantXML);
XmlNodeList elemList2 = xmlDoc2.GetElementsByTagName("applicant");
for (int i = sequenceCounter - 1; i < totalNumberSequences; i++)
{
eachXML[i] = elemList2.Item(i).OuterXml;

}

populateFields(sequenceCounter - 1);
```

}

```
 private void populateFields(int sequenceCounter)
{

    if (sequenceCounter < totalNumberSequences)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc3 = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc3.LoadXml(eachXML[sequenceCounter]);

        if (xmlDoc3.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0] == null)
        {
            string name = "";
            nametextbox.Value = name;
        }
        else
        {
            string name = xmlDoc3.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText;
            nametextbox.Value = name;
        }
}
```

}

first method run image:
[image]

second method run image:
[image]

Comment: make eachXml as class level variable

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Xmlitem
{
    public static string[] eachXML { get; set; }
}
```

I added this class and changed my instance to :

```
Xmlitem.eachXML = new string[totalNumberSequences]
```